# ckeditor not working after upload to server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, ckeditor, text-editor

I used ckeditor in mvc5 project.after I deployed to local machine it work fine in any browser.
But after I upload it to web server it is not working.
I can see the textarea without ckeditor tools.

Comment: Any errors in console? Maybe it expects .min file?

Comment: The configuration of the server and your machine are different?

Comment: No nothing.I`m new to asp.net.I used TinyMCE before and same happend I thought it was a problem with TinyMCE and I remove it and impliment ckedit but same result.I used console and fiddler and every known method but no any progress

Comment: Can you give us a link to see? To me this sounds like it could be a path/URL issue...

Comment: Well the first problem is that /test/Resource/ckeditor.js is completely empty... the reason behind that might be a bit more difficult to find. Sorry. I'm guessing that it actually Should return a 404, but some config prevents it. I think this because `/test/Resource/blah.js` is empty too, while it should definitely be a 404. Maybe check that the file is actually in the server?

Comment: Finally I figure it out.The problem is I place the link to ckeditor.js file in top of view page.After I move it to layout head section now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out.The problem is I place the link to ckeditor.js file in top of view page.After I move it to layout head section now its working fine. I think there is a conflict between if inline jquery run first.